What is better to update a view model's MutableStateFlow, _uiState.update{} or _uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy()?
I am confused what to use, whether to use update or copy for changing/updating the state of UI in Jetpack Compose.
Some say to use
_uiState.update {
    it.copy()
}

Some say to use
_uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy()

Which one would be better to use and why?
I have used copy() a lot of times but still I am not sure if I am updating the uiState efficiently or properly.

Actually both _uiState.update { } and  _uiState.value.copy() are valid for updating state, but they are slightly different in terms of best practices and thread safety.
Using _uiState.update { }
Thread-safety: It prevents issues where multiple threads could attempt to update the state simultaneously, leading to inconsistent states.
Atomicity: It reads the current state and applies modifications in one
operation.
Using _uiState.value.copy()
it is not inherently thread-safe. If multiple threads try to update _uiState at the same time, there could be inconsistencies.
This approach is simpler in single-threaded scenarios, it’s generally less safe in multi-threaded environments, which can be easily occur in  background threads, coroutines
So, which one you should use and when  
Prefer _uiState.update { }: In most cases, it's better to use update { } when dealing with MutableStateFlow because it is thread-safety and atomic. It will protect UI state from race conditions and also ensure consistent updates even in a multi-threaded environment.
Use _uiState.value.copy() -> Very Carefully : This can be fine if you're sure that no other threads will be modifying the state concurrently, single Thread environment.

I would say that both ways are efficient. The core difference between these two approaches is thread-safety.
The update function performs the modification atomically, meaning that it makes sure that there can't be two threads writing to the same MutableStateFlow at the same time. So you should definitely use this when you update your MutableStateFlow from two different places asynchronously, otherwise some updates could be lost.

Updates the MutableStateFlow.value atomically using the specified function of its value.

Also have a look at this article, which points out the dangers of updating a MutableStateFlow concurrently.
Otherwise, if you are not modifying your MutableStateFlow concurrently, using the value field with the copy function is enough, and will be less expensive than update (although the difference might not be significant).

This is only possible with a StateFlow.
And also, be aware that it's not necessarily related to Compose, it's a kotlin-coroutines thing.
You could use either of your approaches -

stateflow.update {...} is an atomic way to do some operation and only emit one state update

stateflow.value = x is basically the same, but it's assigning some new value to your flow.


If you're not using the previous state for something (i.e., you don't need to use copy in your state update) then use stateflow.value, but if you want to create a new state from your old state then it makes sense to use stateflow.update {...} over copy

Although there are already multiple answers explaining the differences, none makes it explicitly clear:
Always use the value property. There is one exception: When the calculation of the new value depends on the old value you need to use the update method. It is less efficient, but it is the only way to guarantee that concurring updates won't get lost.
Therefore, don't use _uiState.value.copy().

The OP asked whether it is better to use _uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy(). In the second paragraph you write: Always use the value property. In your third paragraph, you summarize as don't use _uiState.value.copy(), which seems contradicting.

You should use the value property to set the value, not to calculate the new value. When you need to use the value in the calculation of the new value, you need to use update instead.
